# Increase Observation Space of frozen Lake environment

Tags: openai-gym

Hello I would like to increase the observation Space of Frozen-Lake v0 in open AI Gym.
Is there a way to do this in openai gymenvironment, using spaces like Discrete, Box, MultiDiscrete or some others?

Comment: By increasing the observation space, do mean increasing the grid size?

Comment: Hey, i mean I would like to add a integer to each of the grid, is this possible?

Comment: It is still not clear. Could you add an example of what you want to do with the grid.

Comment: Hey, I would like to add an integer to a state (field) and each time, when the agent steps on this specific field, I want the integer to increase, and after a maximum number of steps, the Agent shall disappear.